# How do I modify the dependencies and rules of a GNU makefile target depending upon the platform (Linux vs. OS X)?

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements, gnu-make

I have a (GNU) makefile with an all target that looks like this:

```
.PHONY: all
all: $(unittest++_tests_exe) $(cmockery_tests_exe)
 @echo Running UnitTest++ tests...
 @./$(unittest++_tests_exe)
 @echo Running Cmockery tests...
 @./$(cmockery_tests_exe)
```

The UnitTest++ tests run on both Linux and Mac OS X, and the Cmockery tests run only on Linux.

How do I modify the dependencies and rules so that `make all` only builds and runs `$(unittest++_tests_exe)` on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[T.E.D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29639/t-e-d)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631166/how-do-i-modify-the-dependencies-and-rules-of-a-gnu-makefile-target-depending-upo/4631175#4631175) triggered me to come up with the following:

```
ifeq ($(uname),Linux)
cmockery_tests_exe = cmockery_tests
else
cmockery_tests_exe = $()
endif

.PHONY: all
all: $(unittest++_tests_exe) $(cmockery_tests_exe)
 @echo Running UnitTest++ tests...
 @./$(unittest++_tests_exe)
ifeq ($(uname),Linux)
 @echo Running Cmockery tests...
 @./$(cmockery_tests_exe)
endif
```

It seems to work, but I welcome your suggestions.

Comment: Does anybody know why on earth `$(uname)` is not working for me but `$(shell uname)` does?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the Right Way to do this is to use something like autoconf.

If you want to hack it, try calling uname and putting the result in a symbol. You can then parse out the relevant parts

Comment: I guess I'm lazy (which is arguably a programmer's virtue), but I have a makefile that's working well and is quite readable.  I don't have any experience with autoconf, and this doesn't seem like enough of a reason to learn it.